# Is the product of a normal subgroup and subgroup always normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then is $HN$ normal?

Comment: Generally, no. Take $N = \{1\}$ for a trivial example. But even excluding that, in general, no.

Comment: A less trivial example is given by $G=S_4, N=\{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\},H=\{(1),(12)\}$. We have $(34) \in HN$, but $(13)(34)(31)=(14) \not \in HN$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant to ask whether $NH$ is normal. The answer is usually no. Let $N=\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

Comment: Hmm... If then I particularised N to be the derived group (G,G)?

Comment: I doubt it very much. Why don't you check for a few finite groups?

Comment: If a subgroup contains $[G,G]$, it is normal. Hence $[G,G]H$ is always a normal subgroup. To prove this, note that $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, and every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.